# Change the font in a GtkTreeView

Tags: c, fonts, gtk, gtktreeview

How can I change the font of a leaf in my gtktreeview? I'd like set the font bold for a particular leaf

Comment: Which language? You'll get more answers if you add the language you're using, also adding some example code (i.e. how you add your items to the GtkTreeView) would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe this thread is some help to you: http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2006-November/msg00187.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've seen the thread, but I don't understand how to set the font for an existing column and a particular node in the tree. Ah, I'm programming in C.

Comment: Ok, you should edit your question with this additional information, I already added the "c" and "gtk" tags to the question so more people with a GTK+ background will see it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using python, but the way to do this must be the same, only adapt the syntax.

In GTK, use PANGO to change fonts. Here in a treeview :

```
import pango, GTK
....
cols = ['Date', 'Index', 'Program', 'Comments', 'Name']
self.treeView.cell = [None] * len(cols)
....
fontT = pango.FontDescription("serif light Oblique 8")
fontO = pango.FontDescription("serif bold 8")
treeView.cell[2].set_property('font-desc', fontT)
treeView.cell[3].set_property('font-desc', fontO)
```

This makes columns 2 ('Program') and 3 ('Comments') of different fonts. Column 3 is bold.

Hope this was helpful.

---

**EDIT :**

Just found a C link :

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-u-pango2/

Answer (score 0):

You must set a data function for the column like this:

```
gtk_tree_view_column_set_cell_data_func(column, renderer, data_func, NULL, NULL);
```

The data function could look like this:

```
void data_func (GtkTreeViewColumn *col,
                GtkCellRenderer   *renderer,
                GtkTreeModel      *model,
                GtkTreeIter       *iter,
                gpointer           user_data)
{
  gboolean active;
  gtk_tree_model_get(model, iter, CHECKED_COLUMN, &active, -1);

  g_debug("xxxxx %u", active);
  if (active)
  {
    g_object_set(renderer, "weight", PANGO_WEIGHT_BOLD, NULL);
  }
  else
  {
    g_object_set(renderer, "weight", PANGO_WEIGHT_NORMAL, NULL);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Pango Markup**. It What you then need is:

1. Use Pango Markup Language within you model (here with `GtkListStore`):

```
GtkListStore *listStore = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
GtkTreeIter rowIter;
gtk_list_store_append(listStore, &rowIter);
gtk_list_store_set(listStore, &rowIter,
    LIST_COL_NAME, "<span foreground='blue'>Blue Title</span>"\
    " usual content", -1);
```

And later, when you create the columns for the `TreeView`, you need to specify `markup` instead of `text`:

```
#define LIST_COL_INDEX_NAME 0 // column index

// ...

GtkTreeViewColumn * col = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes (
         "Column title", renderer,
         "markup", // <--- This is important!
         LIST_COL_INDEX_NAME, NULL);
gtk_tree_view_append_column (treeview, col);
```

#### References

- [Pango markup reference](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Markup.html#pango-parse-markup)