# How do I change the GTK TreeView text size in a C/C++ application at runtime?

Tags: gtk3, font-size, pango

I have been trying to find an example code to changes the text size of a GTK TreeView.

I have seen people using CSS to change the font size. But for me, this option is out of the question - my application does not use CSS.

The closet related answer I can find is [Change the font in a GtkTreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380367/change-the-font-in-a-gtktreeview). But it is in python more than in C and the C link there is broken. Does any one has a snippet of C code showing how it can be done?

I tried to search an example code in C but couldn't find any.